# Looped MediaPlayer Stopping in Thread

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading, audio

I am trying to play a very short audio file repeatedly with a delay. The code I was using is:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.audio);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {        
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                    try {
                        mp.start();
                        android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

The reason I am not using the MediaPlayer loop thing is because I want a delay. This code was working fine, however it locked up my entire application due to the SystemClock.sleep part. So I decided to put it into a thread to use the native sleep() function:

```
Thread th = new Thread(){
        MediaPlayer mp;
        public void run() {

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.audio);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {        
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                    try {
                        mp.start();
                        sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });


    }};
    th.start();
```

Now what happens is that it plays the file once and stops. 
So, I tried removing the sleep function, and that made it weird. The file played about 5 or 6 times and then stopped. Do threads have a time limit? I found this very odd. I want the audio file to keep playing.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the loop function in the media player instead.

Try adding `mp.setLooping(true);` before `mp.start();`